# Maximum setlocal recursion level reached in batch

Tags: batch-file

The task is to replace the reference path with some new path in collection of html files. I used the below code for that and it throws the maximum setlocal recursion level reached  error,

```
@echo off
for /r ".\" %%f in (\html\*.htm) do (
    SETLOCAL
    call :SUB ../icons ../../icons "%%f">"%%f_new" 

    del "%%f"
)
for /r ".\" %%f in (*.htm_new) do rename "%%f" "*.htm"
ENDLOCAL
exit /b

:SUB
call
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
)
exit /b
```

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should ident your code.
The parenthesis aren't balanced, there are more opened than closed parenthesis.

You call a label/function which is a part of your first `FOR /r` loop, that will never work.

Perhaps this is what you want (but I can't even guess what you try withyour code)

```
@echo off
for /r ".\" %%f in (\html\*.htm) do (
    SETLOCAL
    call :SUB ../icons ../../icons "%%f">"%%f_new" 
    del "%%f"
    ENDLOCAL
)
for /r ".\" %%f in (*.htm_new) do rename "%%f" "*.htm"
exit /b

:SUB
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
)
exit /b
```

**After edited your code:**
The setlocal/endlocal should be in the same block, in your case you call `SETLOCAL` for every html file, but only call `ENDLOCAL` once.
But each `SETLOCAL` needs an `ENDLOCAL`

**After your comment:**
You try to modify a html file with percent expansion, that will fail in many cases, as it's tricky to handle the special characters in an html file like `<>&|`.

Btw. Your `For /f` loop to read the file content will fail when a line begins with `]`.

This one should work

```
:SUB
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
        set "line=%%B"        
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%~1=%~2!"
        set "line=!line:*]=!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
)
exit /b
```

But there is a much simpler solution using the repl.bat tool from dbenham

Comment: sorry, my code is having parenthesis but i m issed to add here. now i edited my code. and also i added exit /b in both end. still i got the same error. pls do the needful

Comment: '・ｿ<html' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I set setlocal above the forloop and now its working fine as expected. Thanks for your valuable answers...